# log shipping error postgres

Tags: postgresql

I was performing log shipping from postgres 9.0.4 (redhat ) to 9.0.6 (fedoara14)
but I received an error

```
HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000200000065" from archive
LOG:  record with zero length at 2/65000100
WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data may be missing
HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=minimal without taking a new base backup.
FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because wal_level was not set to "hot_standby" on the master server
HINT:  Either set wal_level to "hot_standby" on the master, or turn off hot_standby here.
LOG:  startup process (PID 9438) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure

ls ../archive/
000000010000000200000051                  000000010000000200000059                  00000001000000020000005F.00000020.backup
000000010000000200000052                  000000010000000200000059.00000020.backup  000000010000000200000060
000000010000000200000053                  00000001000000020000005A                  000000010000000200000061
000000010000000200000054                  00000001000000020000005B                  000000010000000200000061.00000020.backup
000000010000000200000055                  00000001000000020000005B.00000020.backup  000000010000000200000062
000000010000000200000055.00000020.backup  00000001000000020000005C                  000000010000000200000063
000000010000000200000056                  00000001000000020000005D                  000000010000000200000064
000000010000000200000057                  00000001000000020000005E                  000000010000000200000065
000000010000000200000058                  00000001000000020000005F         


ls pg_xlog
000000010000000200000061.00000020.backup  000000010000000200000067  00000001000000020000006A  archive_status
000000010000000200000065                  000000010000000200000068  00000001000000020000006B  RECOVERYXLOG
000000010000000200000066                  000000010000000200000069  00000001000000020000006C


cat recovery.conf 
### RECOVERY 
standby_mode = 'on'
restore_command = 'cp -i  /var/lib/pgsql/9.0/archive/%f %p'
```

when I remove the recovery.conf file from the data/ directory 
and turned off 'hot_standby' in postgresql.conf file then I can start the postgres and can select the data 
I want the secondary postgres should be start in a hot_standby mode

can any one tell me how to get rid of this issue !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check `postgresql.conf` on your master database. According to your log:

```
WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data may be missing
HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=minimal without taking a new base backup.
FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because wal_level was not set to "hot_standby" on the master server
HINT:  Either set wal_level to "hot_standby" on the master, or turn off hot_standby here.
```

The message is pretty informative. You should either use `wal_level = hot_standby` on the master database (consider running a full backup after turning this on), or use `hot_standby = off` on the standby side (this change requires no extra manipulations).

In fact, in order to maintain standby you need either `archive` or `hot_standby` level of WAL, per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL).

If you have activated your standby by removing `recovery.conf` and starting the cluster, then you should re-create standby from the latest full backup.